# server-side rendering mysql limit n rows and paginate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datatables, server-side-rendering

I am using server-side rendering in DataTable.

I have a variable that determines `limit` to number of rows from database.

I am trying to fetch, say, 100 rows, and from DataTable with pagelength of `25`, paginate it upto `4` pages.

Also, if the limit variable is `4` or `10`, or anything less than `pagelength` value, then all records will be displayed in a `single` page.

Here's my code:

```
#get datatable params
$draw = $this->request->input('draw');
$start = $this->request->input('start');
$dt_limit = $this->request->input('length'); // datatable pagination limit

$limit_rows = $this->request->input('limit');

# query
$result_product_urls = DB::table('product_match_unmatches')
        ->select('r_product_url', 'r_image_url_main')
        ->selectRaw('count(distinct s_product_url, r_product_url) as frequency, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(s_image_url, "&s_product_url=", s_product_url) SEPARATOR " | ") as source_products')
        ->groupBy('r_product_url')
        ->where('request_id', '=', $reqId)
        ->orderBy('frequency', 'DESC')
        ->take($limit_rows);

        $recordsTotal =   $result_product_urls->get()->count();
        $urls = $result_product_urls->offset($start)->limit($dt_limit)->get();
```

This will always fetch `25` rows from the database, since the dataTable page-length is `25`.

But I need to limit the rows based on `$limit_rows` value, and not `$dt_limit`.

If I only do `$urls = $result_product_urls->get();`, then if `$limit_rows` value is `100`, all `100` rows are displayed in the same page.

How can I fetch `limit` rows from database, and then paginate through it?

I hope I make my post clear.

Comment: To clarify, in your example of fetch 100 rows and pagelength 25, are you wanting datatables to *not* make an ajax call when you paginate through the 100? By default, with server-side=true, clicking to next page causes ajax request. This *can* be worked around, but I want to be sure this is what you are asking.

Comment: @Aaron number of rows should be defined by limit value passed in as a request parameter by user, and not by datatable's limit and offset parameters. 
But in my case, limit functionality is overridden by the datatable's parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at this, but it's not entirely clear to me the exact thing you are attempting to accomplish based on the code sample.

According to Laravel docs *take* and *limit* appear to be equivalent.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset (bottom of this section)

**What it looks like the code is doing:**

*Using `$limit_rows` value with `->take()` method in the `$result_product_urls` query builder object:*

```php
# query
$result_product_urls = DB::table('product_match_unmatches')
        ->select('r_product_url', 'r_image_url_main')
        ->selectRaw('count(distinct s_product_url, r_product_url) as frequency, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(s_image_url, "&s_product_url=", s_product_url) SEPARATOR " | ") as source_products')
        ->groupBy('r_product_url')
        ->where('request_id', '=', $reqId)
        ->orderBy('frequency', 'DESC')
        ->take($limit_rows); /* <------------- limit_rows HERE */
```

*But then also using `$dt_limit` value with `->limit()` method when setting the `$urls` variable:*

```php
$recordsTotal =   $result_product_urls->get()->count();
$urls = $result_product_urls->offset($start)->limit($dt_limit)->get();/*<-- dt_limit HERE */
```

If you don't want to use `$dt_limit` as a limit then don't use it...? I think maybe what you are trying to do is have a query with a limit on the result set, and then a *sub* limit on that? I can't figure out a reason to want to do that, so I might be missing something. I don't think you can use `->take()` and `->limit()` on the same query.

**Shouldn't this accomplish your goal?:**

```
# query
$result_product_urls = DB::table('product_match_unmatches')
        ->select('r_product_url', 'r_image_url_main')
        ->selectRaw('count(distinct s_product_url, r_product_url) as frequency, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(s_image_url, "&s_product_url=", s_product_url) SEPARATOR " | ") as source_products')
        ->groupBy('r_product_url')
        ->where('request_id', '=', $reqId)
        ->orderBy('frequency', 'DESC'); 
        /* ->take($limit_rows); remove this  */

        $recordsTotal =   $result_product_urls->get()->count();
        $urls = $result_product_urls->offset($start)
                        ->limit($limit_rows) /* set limit to $limit_rows */
                        ->get();
```

If not, then maybe you can clarify.

Answer (score -1):

use offset alongwith limit i.e. 
$users = DB::table('users')->skip(10)->take(5)->get();
or 
$users = DB::table('users')->offset(10)->limit(5)->get();